# Running C# sample code in command line

Tags: c#, windows, dll, command-line, leap-motion

Newb question here: I'm trying to run this sample c# code from https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/CSharpandUnity/Guides/Sample_CSharp_Tutorial.html for the Leap Motion.

> Running the sample
>
> To run the sample application:
>
> Compile the sample application: On Windows, make sure that Sample.cs
>   and either LeapCSharp.NET3.5.dll or LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll are in the
>   current directory. Run the following command in a command-line prompt
>   (using the proper library reference for the .NET framework you are
>   using): csc /reference:LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll /platform:x86 /target:exe
>   Sample.cs Note: use the `csc` compiler from the appropriate version
>   of the .NET framework.

How do I figure out what .NET framework I have?

How do I make sure that Sample.cs and either LeapCSharp.NET3.5.dll or LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll are in the current directory? This simply mean to put this folders in my CD right? Then execute:

```
csc /reference:LeapCSharp.NET4.0.dll /platform:x86 /target:exe
Sample.cs
```

Can someone translate what each segment in that line actually means?

Comment: You should be able to see your .NET version listed in the Control Panel under the Programs section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, type `dir` to see what's in your current directiory. If `sample.cs` and the appropriate `.DLL` are there, you should be set to go.

To see what version of .NET you have, you can just type `clrver` in the Visual Studio Command Prompt. Just FYI, if you see version 2.0, that'll actually be 3.5 in this case (.NET 3.5 actually compiles on the 2.0 compiler, while 4.0 is an entirely different *thing*).

And a breakdown of the command:

```
csc         // C Sharp Compiler
/reference  // Reference a DLL not in the GAC
/platform   // Compile for 32bit or 64bit?
/target     // Producing a DLL or EXE?
Sample.cs   // File to actually compile
```